# How to use REGEXEXTRACT values in a SUMIF formula?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have exported browser sizes from Google Analytics and made this Google Sheet:

[image]

**Explanation of columns**

- Column A - Browser sizes (static)
- Column B - Browser width extracted with the following formula: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"^(.*)x[^x]*$")`
- Column C - Users (static)
- Column D - Sum of column C

Now I wan't to calculate the percentage of users using a browser width less than 1400 and 1000 in column E and F.

I'm using this formula `=SUMIF(B1:B598,"<1400",C1:C598)/D2*100`, which should be correct, but it returns 0. I guess that's because the values of column B are dynamic from the regex and not static values.

How can I use the dynamic regex values from column B in my SUMIF formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you get with the regex are text strings. The `sum()` function will treat them as zero. To make it work, convert the text strings to numbers like this:

```
=value(regexextract(A2, "\d+"))
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I did try to format the column as number, but looks like that didn't actual turn the values into numbers.